# How Biases and Prejudices Deviate the Philosophy of Peace in round table meeting of world politics

Tags: history-of-philosophy, political-philosophy, sociology, practical-ethics, applied-philosophy

Why do politically strengthened nations deviate from the ideal of peace building and misuse power through bias, prejudice, and subjugation of others towards "peace," but not actual, **absolute** Peace but narrow-minded ideas of what is "peaceful," here or there?

Comment: Is there any chance you might be able to unpack your question a little further..? What have you been reading or studying that's made this an interesting question in your study of philosophy?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I am asking, How strong developed nations subjugate other *developing* nations about definition and application of **Peace** based on leaders biased prejudices leading an intergovernmental organization? basically heading and conducting conciliate, and deviant all members from the absolute intent. Hope this will make a sense ...